# What is the cause of this function looping with buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, loops

I had problems with some code lately, and I need help fixing it. Basically, I use jQuery to append buttons to a website. I use tons of functions in order to make a mini-rpg game for that peculiar website. 
For example, a button closer and a button maker. Both are functions; the button maker uses `.append()` to make some buttons to the game's UI, and the button closer uses `.remove()` to remove those buttons. Then, I use `.on("click",function(){ //code })` to bind `onClick` to some buttons. The functions also include a bunch of other functions with buttons to go back to a previous function and etc.
Unfortunately, it seems they loop between themselves endlessly. I believe the buttons are the ones causing it. Any ideas to fix?
**I suggest not running the code, as it can either crash the tab or make it unresponsive.**
Example code:

```js
function buttonMaker1(){
  $('body').append('<button id="btn1">Button 1</button>');
}
function buttonMaker2(){
  $('body').append('<button id="btn1">Button 1</button>');
  $('body').append('<button id="btn2">Button 2</button>');
}

function buttonRemover(){
  if($('#btn1').length){
    $('#btn1').remove();
  }
  if($('#btn2').length){
    $('#btn2').remove();
  }
}
function menu(){
  buttonRemover();
  buttonMaker2();
  $('#btn1').on("click",myFunction());
  $('#btn2').on("click",myFunction());
}
function myFunction(){
  buttonRemover();
  buttonMaker1();
  $('#btn1').on("click",menu());
}
menu();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Should be `$('#btn1').on("click",myFunction);` and `$('#btn1').on("click",menu);` etc. Notice the parentheses I have removed.

Comment: When binding event-handlers you need to pass a *reference* to your functions and not to invoke them (`on('click', someFunc)`). Also, your `menu` is calling `myFunction` and `myFunction` is calling `menu`, no wonder it gets stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you bind a handler to a function, just give the function name. Putting parentheses after the function name calls the function at that time, not when the event occurs.

```js
function buttonMaker1(){
  $('body').append('<button id="btn1">Button 1</button>');
}
function buttonMaker2(){
  $('body').append('<button id="btn1">Button 1</button>');
  $('body').append('<button id="btn2">Button 2</button>');
}

function buttonRemover(){
  if($('#btn1').length){
    $('#btn1').remove();
  }
  if($('#btn2').length){
    $('#btn2').remove();
  }
}
function menu(){
  buttonRemover();
  buttonMaker2();
  $('#btn1').on("click",myFunction);
  $('#btn2').on("click",myFunction);
}
function myFunction(){
  buttonRemover();
  buttonMaker1();
  $('#btn1').on("click",menu);
}
menu();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```